# JavaScript: setting main div tag height to zero which makes all the sub divs have a height of zero

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I just want to use some css to make the height of a div 0 which also makes all the heights of the sub divs 0. I then want to call a javascript function which when clicked it makes the height of the main div 100%.

Here is the code that I have written:

**HTML**

```
<div class="menuTitle" id="ButtonsTopStyle" onclick="ButtonsTop">CONNECTING   RODS</div>
<div class="buttonsTop" >
    <img src="Images/ButtonA.gif" alt="ImageA" class="smallButtons" />
    <img src="Images/ButtonA.gif" alt="ImageA" class="smallButtons" />
    <img src="Images/ButtonA.gif" alt="ImageA" class="smallButtons" />
</div>

<div class="menuTitle" id="ButtonsBottomStyle" onclick="ButtonsBottom">CRANKSHAFTS</div>
<div class="buttonsBottom">
    <img src="Images/ButtonA.gif" alt="ImageA" class="smallButtons" />
    <img src="Images/ButtonA.gif" alt="ImageA" class="smallButtons" />
    <img src="Images/ButtonA.gif" alt="ImageA" class="smallButtons" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.smallButtons {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-left: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    background-color: white;
}

.menuTitle {
    color: white;
    font-family: "Arial";
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

.buttonsTop {
    margin-left: 23px;
}

.buttonsBottom {
    height: 0;
    margin-left: 23px;
}
```

The css I have written doesnt make the height of the .buttonBottom zero they are still being displayed on the page. I don't want them to be displayed on the page

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function ButtonsBottom() {
    document.getElementById("ButtonsTopStyle").style.height = "0";
    document.getElementById("ButtonsBottomStyle").style.height = "100%";
}

function ButtonsTop() {
    document.getElementById("ButtonsBottomStyle").style.height = "0";
    document.getElementById("ButtonsTopStyle").style.height = "100%";
}
```

As you can see I want the buttonsBottom to not be visible on the page when it loads but when you click on the `onclick="ButtonBottom"` div it makes the height 100% and makes the `onclick="ButtonsTop"` div have a height of 0

Comment: Can you try `.buttonsBottom img {height: 0;}`?

Comment: The elements with the IDs `ButtonsTopStyle` and `ButtonsBottomStyle` are not wrappers for the image elements, they only contain some text.

Comment: Instead of `document.getElementById("ButtonsTopStyle")` and `document.getElementById("ButtonsBottomStyle")`, try `document.querySelector(".buttonsTop")` and `document.querySelector(". buttonsBottom")`

Comment: @MattCremeens I have done that before and it works but then I cant make the javascript functions make the height 100% can I?

Comment: You can put `ids` on your `img` tags and then make the `height = 100%` on those `ids`.

Comment: @MattCremeens I would have to use ids with different names and that will look messy because you cant use multiple of the same id name can you?

Comment: @MattCremeens Thanks I'm an idiot but it still doesnt seem to work :( you can use onclick function of divs cant you?

Comment: Yes, you can click on any html element.

Comment: @MattCremeens sorry to be a pain I have got it all working but I have changed my <img> tags to <asp:ImageButton> tags and whenever I click onto a button it resets everything to how it looked when the page loads. So basically the CSS has overwritten the JavaScript style I set do you know how I could fix this?

Comment: What was wrong with using the `img` tags?

Comment: @MattCremeens I want to add functionality to them

Comment: I would suggest you edit your question with your updated code.

Comment: @MattCremeens I figured it out thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an

```
overflow:hidden;
```

to your `.buttonsBottom` div

Your div is expanding in height to accommodate your content.

What I'd suggest is adding an additional class of

```
.hidden {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
 }
```

to your CSS and then modifying your JavaScript to add/remove this class as needed.

The other option would be to use `display: none;` and `display: block;` instead of height. Which would be my preferred method as long as you aren't aiming for a transition effect on height when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
function ButtonsBottom() {
    document.getElementById("ButtonsTopStyle").style.height = "0";
    document.getElementById("ButtonsBottomStyle").style.height = "0%";
}

function ButtonsTop() {
    document.getElementById("ButtonsBottomStyle").style.height = "0";
    document.getElementById("ButtonsTopStyle").style.height = "0%";
}
```

Comment: I need to make the css work first I have editted my question so that it is in more detail about the css. The CSS I have written doesnt make the height of the buttonsBottom 0 for some reason!